# How to preserve the Cdata section in the XML String while converting into document

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am having XML data as a string and in that XML, one of the nodes contains the CDATA section
While converting the XML string into Document in java, the CDATA section was removed.
How can I preserve it?

**Xml string contains the following values**

```
<node1> <subnode> <![CDATA[test]]></subnode> </node1>
```

**java code used while converting the string to document**

```
ByteArrayInputStream gmdDetadatainBytesIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
DocumentBuilderFactory gmdDocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder gmdDocumentBuilder = gmdDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document metadata = gmdDocumentBuilder.parse(gmdDetadatainBytesIs);
```

Comment: You'll have to show us some code on how you process the string into the Document. (My bet is on that you process text, but not cdata)

Comment: What Java API or libraries are you using? Also, why do you think you NEED it to be serialized with CDATA? Is it to preserve original as much as possible to aid in diff, or is it because you *think* you need it? If the data is properly escaped when serialized, then it won't matter. It is similar to a preference for numeric entities vs named entities - the XML parser will handle it for you and you shouldn't really care.

Comment: I have edited the description. Can you please check it

Comment: That code doesn't show at any point that your `Document` object doesn't contain a CDATA section node. As you have also tagged the question for XSLT I guess you pass that `Document` on to a `Transformer`; the XPath/XSLT/XQuery data model doesn't know any CDATA sections, it only has text nodes so with (normal) XSLT processing your XSLT stylesheet sees both `<subnode><![CDATA[test]]></subnode>` and `<subnode>test</subnode>` as a `subnode` element node having a text node child with the value `test`. LexEv can preprocess XML to convert CDATA sections to markup.